# Caching proxy server with just a router?

Tags: router

Trying to set up a caching proxy server using a router running tomato firmware.  I'm not sure if this is even possible, but figured i'd give it a try.

Answer (score 3):

It is theoretically possible, but with one major **caveat** - storage. Not sure why *anyone* would want to try it though. Good luck!

You will need to solve the storage problem as Chris suggested. You have several options depending on your router's capabilities:

1. USB drive - only if your router has a USB port **or** if one can be soldered directly onto the board.
2. SD card - some routers have the ability to interface to SD/MMC card devices. Again, you may need to solder the connector if interface is available on the board.
3. NFS/SMB - your last resort is to mount a network share on your router. Most of these WRT firmware allow you to do that.

Your next problem would be with RAM. Unless you got one with 64Mb or more RAM, you will truly be pushing the limits. However, you can possibly do with less RAM if you configure the caching software to reduce the RAM cache and use only the disk cache.

If all you want is to have a caching proxy on your network, why not consider setting a proper one up as a transparent proxy and the configuring your router to force HTTP connections through the external proxy.

Comment: I will just add that I run a "real" linux box as a cache at home, and along with a well set up bind the result is just wonderful.